# Limitation on using getPopulatedFieldsAsMap method

Tags: apex, sobject

I am excited to getPopulatedFieldsAsMap that being released on [Summer 16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm) . I tried to run query however some of field does not return value. I thought it was bug but somehow it should be fixed in [Spring 17](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=206000000) because now already Summer 19.

I have some quick testing and find out that if I limit the query, I will able to see the field value. I am not sure if there any documentation on size of fields return limitation.

Here is my sample code :

```
/**  certain field fail to return value  
quote = [SELECT Id, Name ,Owner.Name,RecordType.Name, Date_Submitted__c , Date_Approved__c , Actual_Final_Approver__c , Primary__c , Status__c,
            Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.Name,Account__c,Account__r.Name,SalesRep__c,Pre_Sales__c,Legal_Entity__c,
             Quote_Name__c,Quote_Summary__c ,Discount_Reason__c FROM Quote__c  
             WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('quoteId')];

 */
 //this will return value 
 quote = [SELECT Id, Discount_Reason__c FROM Quote__c  
             WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('quoteId')];

   mapQuote = quote.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();        
   system.debug('@@@ map size '+ mapQuote.size());//map size only 20 ??? 

   //this will fail if I used 
   System.assert(mapQuote.ContainsKey('Discount_Reason__c'), 'Discount_Reason test');
   for (String fieldName : mapQuote.keySet()) {
        System.debug('@@@ field name is ' + fieldName + ', value is ' + 
            mapQuote.get(fieldName));
    }
```

I am using class with version 46.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I feel is `Discount_Reason__c` would be null and hence it was not part of `mapQuote`.

I quickly wrote a test class to test this behaviour.

```
Account a = new Account();
a.name = 'TestMapAccount1';
insert a;
a = [select Id,Name,Type  from Account where id=:a.Id];
Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = a.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

System.assert(fieldsToValue.containsKey('Type') ,'Type is Not populated'); //It broke
```

Even if I querried `Type` it was not part of map keys as the value was null.

Comment: You're correct - `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` only has a map of populated fields (as the name suggests), and any field that's `null` will not show up in that map (even if it's included in the SOQL query).  I just tested this myself as well

Comment: Ahh..if that the case how we can compare fieldname in query is match in the query result dynamically. I google around but only find whether we can only get all fieldname from describe object or specifically state field name(i am not expert enough) . I wonder any api that enable to extract field name from soql so we can compare with result? Because currently I plan to put all the fieldname is string then use dynamic apex.